# How to append tables in appscript (Google Docs) above all other tables

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I'm using appendTable() to append table. It gets appended below the tables I already have. I want it to be appended above them. Have anyone does this before?

Here is the code i am using ( with comments):

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  //Creates a new manu item "Ledermøte" that triggers the function insertMeetingTemplate
  ui.createMenu("Ledermøte")
    .addItem("Opprett nytt møte", "insertMeetingTemplate")
    .addToUi();
}
function insertMeetingTemplate() {
  //Gets the current document body
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

  //Gets the document for where the template tables are stored
  let templateDoc = DocumentApp.openById(
    "xxxxx"
  );

  //Gets the body for the template document
  let templateBody = templateDoc.getBody();

  //Gets the two tables in the template document
  var tables = templateBody.getTables();
  var copiedTable = tables[0].copy();
  var copiedTable2 = tables[1].copy();

  //Appends the two tables in the current docuemnt
  body.appendTable(copiedTable);
  body.appendTable(copiedTable2);
}
```

So the goal is..always append above all other tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `It gets appended below the tables i already have. I want it to be appended above them.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and  output situations you expect as the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Use [`insertTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-table)

The meaning of "append" is literally "add something to the *end* of". What you are looking for is to "prepend" or "insert".

There is no `prepend` method, but you can use the method [`insertTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-table) on the `body` like this:

```js
//Prepends the two tables in the current document
body.insertTable(0, copiedTable);
body.insertTable(0, copiedTable2);
```

The method takes two arguments:

1. The index position, which, since you are prepending, is always going to be 0.
2. The table.

There are also other variations of the method which take different arguments, but this is the one I believe that you need.

#### Reference

- [`insertTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex,-table)
- [`body` methods reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertTable(Integer))

Comment: this worked great! I have some text paragraph and stuff before the tables so want to prepend append after that, will have to try abit more. But your solution works for prepending!:)